# Single MYSQL regex to cover rows with a certain character in start, end, both or none

Tags: mysql, str-replace, mysql-5.7

Say that I want to remove a certain string from a MYSQL column data, e.g `NOTE`.
In the database, the structure of the data can be `PEN, PAPER, NOTE`, `PEN, NOTE, PAPER`, `NOTE`, etc.
Since I cannot predict where is the comma character placed,
I have these UPDATE statements.

```
UPDATE from table
SET column = replace(column, ',NOTE','')
WHERE column like '%NOTE%';

UPDATE from table
SET column = replace(column, 'NOTE,','')
WHERE column like '%NOTE%';

UPDATE from table
SET column = replace(column, 'NOTE','')
WHERE column like '%NOTE%';
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this, instead of having three UPDATE statements?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0 so you can use the new REGEXP_REPLACE() function?

Comment: I am using 5.7, so functions from 8 cannot be used. I also cannot update for certain reasons.

Comment: Don't put more than one value in a column and you won't have this problem. Recommend reading about normalization.

Comment: @danblack, I don't assume this is a comma-separated list of discrete values. The OP could be trying to remove a word from some natural text. Besides, "don't do that" isn't an answer to the question even if they are using an inadvisable comma-separated list.

Comment: I agree with @danblack.  Your efforts would be much better spent just fixing your data model, rather than trying to regex olympics with `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: For some reason, I do not have an option to replace the version nor change the data type of the column. Thank you @danblack and Bill, and Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing string-manipulation in SQL is hardly ever elegant, so there's a limit to how much we can improve your task.

But you can do what you describe in one UPDATE this way:

```
UPDATE from table
SET column = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column, ',NOTE',''), 'NOTE,', ''), 'NOTE', '')
WHERE column like '%NOTE%';
```

This has the usual caveats about matching word boundaries, so `NOTE` will match larger words like `NOTEWORTHY`, etc. Not much you can do about that unless you upgrade to MySQL 8.0.